# Почему в коде не подсвечиваются ошибки ESLint?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

В консоли отображаются ошибки ESLint, но в самом коде ничего не подсвечивается. Я предполагаю, что проблема может быть в том, что я пересела на другое устройство и что-то недонастроила в проекте.

Моя IDE - WebStorm, перейдя в Settings -> Language -> JavaScript -> ESLint выбрала пункт Manual Eslint configuration и указала пути до ESLint и его конфигурации в проекте, также добавила плагин ESLint, но все это не исправило мою проблему

У меня очень большой файл eslintsrc.json и у моих коллег все работает отлично, также у меня все работало на моем старом ноутбуке, поэтому проблема точно не в конфигурации. Мне кажется, что когда я клонировала проект с репозитория на новый ноутбук я что-то не добавила в настройках webstorm.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]